# QtGui.QPushButton.clicked.connect() with function that takes arguments

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I would like to run a function that takes arguments (for instance `my_func(int, str, int)`) when a QtGui.QPushButton is clicked.  The following code

```
my_btn = QtGui.QPushButton()
my_btn.clicked.connect(my_func(my_int, my_str, my_second_int))
```

produces the following RuntimeError: `Failed to connect signal clicked()`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `my_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: my_func(my_int, my_str, my_second_int))`.

Comment: Using lambda don't work for me when use buttons inside a table, seems like connect slot keeps parameters from last record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `connect`, you only pass the callable function

```
my_btn.clicked.connect(my_func)
```

In your example, you're *actually calling the `my_func` function* before the connection code is ever run.  So it's trying to connect whatever value is returned from `my_func`, and it's not working.

What you want to do is create a `partial` function, which is a function that already has some or all of the function arguments pre-filled.  Python has a function in the standard library that can do this called `functools.partial`

```
from functools import partial

my_btn.clicked.connect(partial(my_func, my_int, my_str, my_second_int))
```

This creates a *partial* function that will call `my_func` with the positional arguments `my_int`, `my_str`, and `my_second_int`, and that partial function is connected to the button `clicked` signal.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it includes an explanation of why what I was doing did not work, but I think that ekhumoro's solution is simpler.